# I am trying to import a custom class and it is saying it cant be resolved

Tags: java, import

I am trying to import a Class that has my JTable code in it and I keep getting cant be resolved.
I am trying to import: BuildTables.Java into four.java and none of my attempts at importing it work.

I am using vscode latest release with the java extension pack installed. I am able to import other custom classes in my project into other classes. But BuildTables.Java wont import into anything. Where am I Going wrong?

```
package gui;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class BuildTables {
   
   public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
      Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector();
      int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

      for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; ++column) {
         columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
      }

      Vector data = new Vector();

      while(rs.next()) {
         Vector<Object> vector = new Vector();

         for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; ++columnIndex) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
         }

         data.add(vector);
      }

      return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
   }

   public final boolean fiction() {
      return false;
   }

   public final boolean nonFiction() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Four.Java

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import gui.BuildTables;
import gui.BuildTables.buildTableModel;
import BuildTables;



class four implements ActionListener {
   // $FF: synthetic field
   final gui this$0;
   // $FF: synthetic field
   private final JTextField val$producerField;
   // $FF: synthetic field
   private final JTextField val$plantField;
   // $FF: synthetic field
   private final JTextField val$controlField;
   BuildTables bt = new BuildTables();
   DbInfo w = new DbInfo();

   four(gui var1, JTextField var2, JTextField var3, JTextField var4) {
      this.this$0 = var1;
      this.val$producerField = var2;
      this.val$plantField = var3;
      this.val$controlField = var4;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      String type = "2";
      String prodText = this.val$producerField.getText().trim();
      String plantText = this.val$plantField.getText().trim();
      String ctrlText = this.val$controlField.getText().trim();
      if (prodText != null && !prodText.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && plantText != null && !plantText.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
         
         JTable table = new JTable();

         try {
            table = w.dbInfo(type, ctrlText, prodText, plantText);
         } finally {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, new JScrollPane(table));
         }
      } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, "Must enter in both both producer and plant number");
         this.this$0.bt.fiction();
      }

   }
}
```

EDIT
[PIC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJl5w.png)

[Import Statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QU0V.png)

Comment: Since both are in the package named `gui`, you do not need to import class `BuildTables` at all in class `four`. Just remove the line: `import BuildTables;` (and other lines that import from the package `gui`).

Comment: Are you asking why `import gui.BuildTables;` works, and `import BuildTables;` - does not?

Comment: @Jesper When i take out the reference (import) I still have the compile error.
See Pic one. (in Edit)

Comment: I also tried to compile via command line.                                                                    
    `PS C:\Users\jewell\Documents\GitHub\Local-Repo\ProdLookUp22\src> javac 
     .\gui\four.java
     .\gui\four.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
     BuildTables bt = new BuildTables();
     ^
     symbol:   class BuildTables
     location: class four
     .\gui\four.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
      DbInfo w = new DbInfo();
      ^`